# Prove that for $a > 0$, $\exp(x + a) > \exp(x) + a$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I'm struggling to find a concrete proof of the following statement / inequality:

Let $0 < a << \infty$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$ \exp(x + a) > \exp(x) + a,$$ or

$$ \exp(x + a) - \exp(x) - a > 0.$$

The limiting case when $a \rightarrow 0$ yields zero. The scalar $a$ is always finite, the case $a \rightarrow \infty$ does not exist.

I'm struggling to find a source to back it up.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The inequality is, in general, false. But, if $a>0$ then it is certainly true for all nonnegative $x$

Comment: If you add the assumption that $x \ge 0$, the inequality is true. As stated at the moment, it is not true. And a hint for the solution: differentiate the equation with respect to $a$

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(x)=e^{x+a}-e^x-a=e^x(e^a-1)-a$. The goal is to show that this function is always positive.

We have $f'(x)=e^{x+a}-e^x$ for any $x$. Moreover, we have $e^a>1$ since $a>0$. As $e^x$ is always positive, we have $e^xe^a>e^x$, which gives $e^{x+a}-e^x>0$. Hence, $f'(x)>0$ for any $x$. This means that $f(x)$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.

But it could be that the function starts increasing from below the x-axis. If you have an added assumption, for example: $x\geq \ln(\frac{a}{e^a-1})$, then we can get the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{e^{x+a}}{e^x+a}$$ $$=\frac{e^{x}\cdot e^a}{e^x+a}$$ If $a\ge1,\:\:$ $e^a>a$ (this is trivial) so the fraction yields a value $>1$ which means that the numerator is larger than the denominator or simply $e^{x+a}>e^x+a$

But if $0<a<1$ then the opposite happens and $e^{x+a}<e^x+a$

If you're wondering how I determined which function will grow faster or decrease faster. Just take the derivatives. And you'll find yourself.